# Use busy loop application on multicore box

Tags: c++, linux, posix, message-queue

Is it ok to use busy loop application on multicore box?

I have a couple of applications, which read messages from POSIX message queue, do its processing and again wait for new ones. But, as I understand, mq_timedreceive is quite expensive operation and if application do mq_receive on O_NONBLOCK queue it performs better (with less latency). So if I reserve a couple of CPUs (from 12) for non blocking messages processing, will it be ok?

Comment: Try to avoid it, both esthetically (including ability to scale up your computing) and energy-wise (a server consume more power on busy wait than on idle wait).

Answer (score 1):

> all, is it ok to use busy loop application on multicore box?

Regardless of the equipment, yes it's okay to use a busy wait.  No, it's not advised, and no, it's rarely necessary, but sure -- it's your computer, your application, go for it!

> But, as I understand, mq_timedreceive is quite expensive operation and if application do mq_receive on O_NONBLOCK queue it performs better (with less latency). So if I reserve a couple of CPUs (from 12) for non blocking messages processing, will it be ok?

You have the kind of doubt that can only be cured with data.  Take measurements, see if indeed it is as expensive an operation as you think it is.  Nothing SO tells you will be worth half as much as that.  Your application has performance deadlines measured in milliseconds, microseconds, or nanoseconds (or throughput numbers in the hundreds/thousands/millions of operations per sec).  This combined with your target hardware's capability will dictate which solutions are appropriate.